# React Image Loading problem. Frame by frame

Tags: html, css, reactjs, imageview

There is a problem of React Image loading.
images loading frame by frame.
The Video is below.
https://streamable.com/s/h1xij/mdgbpf

Comment: Can you please also share what have you tried to solve the issue, just giving a video isn't gonna help the community to give an appropriate solution

Comment: this has nothing to do with React Image, but with the size of these images, it looks like they are too big. Try optimizing them

Comment: There is no interesting code block in there. standart <img src={xxx} /> components. if you want, I will share code blocks.

Comment: this is not too big file. one of them about 80kb.
Also I dont want to load image frame by frame. This has been loaded after that show on website. it does not matter any size of images.
 link is below. http://178.128.68.183/images/7d5abcef-3458-4ba4-8016-589ba848da79.png

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behavior of the browser. If you want to show the image once it is downloaded completely then you have to use `lazy loading` concept.

This library probably helps you https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload

Demo: https://twobin.github.io/react-lazyload/examples/#/image?_k=vhbmrq

Comment: Thank you laktherock but I did try 4-5 lazy loading library. this is not work for me.

Comment: Also this is not working. You can check this video. https://streamable.com/s/6frq5/vyihpf

Comment: That's just sample implementation. If you give placeholder to that image it will work fine. please refer to this demo you will understand https://twobin.github.io/react-lazyload/examples/#/placeholder?_k=mr8n0p

Comment: I am going to check it then I will write about result.